# Filtering by tags not working when using aws ec2 describe-instances from command line (cli)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm currently attempting to write an aws ec2 query from the command line (in AWS Linux, not that it should matter). I am trying to set a filter that matches both of the following:

1. Shows those instances that are in the off state (code 80), and;
2. Shows those instances who have a tag "ShortPurpose" whose value is "Fleet".

What is actually happening is that all instances in the off state are being returned, regardless of if they have the tag "ShortPurpose":"Fleet" set.

My instances are set up as so:

```
+-------------+--------------+------------------------+--+
| Instance ID |     Tag      |       Tag Value        |  |
+-------------+--------------+------------------------+--+
| i-09876     | ShortPurpose | Fleet                  |  |
|             | Organisation | UmbrellaCorp           |  |
|             | Name         | cloud-01               |  |
|             | Owner        | ORG-UMBR-ELLA          |  |
|             | Purpose      | Cloud processing fleet |  |
+-------------+--------------+------------------------+--+
|             |              |                        |  |
| i-12345     |  (no tags)   |                        |  |
|             |              |                        |  |
+-------------+--------------+------------------------+--+
```

The command I am using is:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId" --filters "Name=tag:ShortPurpose,Values=Fleet,Name=instance-state-code,Values=80"
```

The results are the standard array style response. The instance state is successfully filtered upon, but not the tags.

Comment: You need space between filters and don't need quotation marks: `Name=tag:ShortPurpose,Values=Fleet Name=instance-state-code,Values=80`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to verify your command and it **produces errors** as you wrote it:

```
Error parsing parameter '--filters': Second instance of key "Name" encountered for input:
Name=tag:ShortPurpose,Values=Fleet,Name=instance-state-code,Values=80
                                   ^
This is often because there is a preceeding "," instead of a space.
```

However, I was able to **successful use** it on my sandbox instances as follows:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
     --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId" \
     --filters Name=tag:ShortPurpose,Values=Fleet Name=instance-state-code,Values=80
```

Comment: Thanks. 
The trick is that each filter must be treated separately, and I had had them grouped with quotes. The answer I've posted works, but I'll mark yours as correct because you took the time to reply, and yours also works.

Comment: @anakaine Thanks. I run several instances, tagged them to your use-case to verify that:-)

Comment: This seemed to have broken recently for me too. Seems like an AWS API change?

Comment: @four43 Could be difference between AWS CLI v1 and v2?

Answer (score 3):

I have discovered in one example in the AWS doumentation that I had the wrong query format. The correct query is:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId" --filters "Name=tag-value,Values=Fleet" "Name=instance-state-code,Values=80"
```

Note that I'm ignoring the ShortPurpose tag and instead hunting directly for the value, which may exist in any tag.